# How to express "nice to hear from you" on telephone call in business situation?

Tags: phrase-requests

I am expecting a call from a staff management company who will call me.

I want to reply that I am happy that they call me. How do I say this in professional (british) english?

> Nice to hear from you
>
> Glad to hear from you
>
> Great to hear from you
>
> Please to hear from you

So the context is:

```
"Hi, this is xxx form xxx company, you applied for the job ad xxx, do you have time?"

"Good morning, yes. I am glad to hear from you."
```

Is this correct to say?

Comment: I also think one should be careful about sarcasm here ; couldn't some of these sentences accidentally sound a little like "at last, you're calling" ?

Comment: You might want to check out the [ell.se] site. You can read a little more about it at [this meta question](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/3722).

Comment: Just say "Sure, thanks for calling. I can talk now."  Don't say anything about being "pleased", it's just not business-like, it sounds silly..  You say things like "hear from you..." only in relation to family communications. Do not use the phrase "hear form you" at all, it sounds weird in business.  You could MAYBE say "Oh, hi, I'm glad you called - sure I can talk now."

Answer (score 3):

**"Thank you for calling"** seems to fill the bill.

Comment: "Thank you for getting back to me" would also be an appropriate variation, given the context.

Comment: You only say "thanks for getting back to me" to an **inferior**.  You don't say that to your boss. (It's unclear what the OP is asking.)

Answer (score 1):

Most of your suggested phrases carry some baggage. Of those, "Pleased" comes closest to neutral, IMO, but I'd suggest "Good to hear from you" as an even more neutral choice.

Answer (score 1):

**Hello, [name].  I'm happy/pleased to hear from you.**

This is cordial and appropriately formal.